# Simple List filter & Search filter with dc.js?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Would someone be able to give an example of how to create a list box filter with dc.js? as well as a search box filter?

I'm trying to create a dashboard with dc.js and instead of filtering through all distinct values using a bar chart, I'm trying to make a listbox with buttons. Is this easy to do?

Similarly, what would be the simplest way to create a search box to filter the data?

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### List box

Sometimes the names of UI elements are ambiguous, but I think you're referring to a select widget, which is available in dc.js 2.1+ as [`dc.selectMenu`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.selectMenu.html).

[Demo](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/select.html)

#### Search box

[Pull Request #936](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/936) implements this. Please try it out and leave your review on the PR.

It's available with the current latest dc.js [in this branch](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/tree/input-filter).

Comment: Amazing! Thank you Gordon! I'm trying it out now.